# What Library to Play Audio in React Native

Tags: react-native, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm pretty new to react native, and I've only build one or two really basic projects. I think creating an app to play mp3 (that are inside the actual project) would be fun. I've done this in swift with xcode using AVAudioPlayer, and I'm just wondering if it is the same library to do this in react native.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries playing Audio but I recommend [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player) provides audio playback, external media controls, background mode and more!

Comment: +++ Absolutely it is the best choice for RN